# Bash - command not found error in if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, command

I have a problem at line 14 and 16 where there are the nested if statments. It returns me command not found error, but I tested that part of code and it's ok used elsewhere.

```
#passing the argument page page.html
cat $1 | grep -o "wp-cli.org/commands/cache/\w*/\"" > temp.txt
#creating all pdf files
for i in $(cat temp.txt)
do 
source=$(echo $i | grep -o -P "wp-cli.org/commands/cache/\w+")
dest=$(echo $i | grep -o -P "\w+/\"" | grep -o -P "\w+")
#echo $source $dest
wkhtmltopdf $source $dest".pdf"
pdfCount=$(ls *pdf | wc -l)
echo $pdfCount
if [ ! -f sample.pdf ]
then
 if [$pdfCount -eq 1] 
 then
    firstPdf=$dest".pdf" 
 fi
 if [$pdfCount -eq 2]
 then
    pdfunite $firstPdf $dest".pdf" sample.pdf
 fi
else
    pdfunite $dest".pdf" oldsample.pdf sample.pdf
    mv sample.pdf oldsample.pdf
fi
done
```

Anyone has an idea about? Thanks...

Comment: Where did you learn to write this code?

Comment: I read some books but it's a long time I haven't created scripts, why?

Comment: learn to use (and understand the output of) http://shellcheck.net . As a matter of defensive programming, there are very few cases where you don't want to use dbl-quotes around variables, so `"$firstPdf"` will save you from some headaches in the future if you start getting filenames like `Contract 2017`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I need to study more about programming in bash...

Comment: What do you want achieve? (wondering about the "big picture") :) Too many problematic constructions in the script (grepping html, unquoted variables, UUOC, UUOE, reading lines using `for ... cat`,  etc)  - so... just wondering. :)

Comment: I need to create a pdf of the wp-cli documentation to use on my tablet. I almost there only need to get how pass an external parameter to grep as regex. I change the version, now I'm trying to get the url and create the pdf file with all link in the doc...

Answer (score 10):

You need a space after the [ and before the ]

Comment: ... and a space after the `if` too!

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces after the opening bracket and before the closing one in a test statement :

```
[$pdfCount -eq 1]
```

Should be :

```
[ $pdfCount -eq 1 ]
```

Suppose `pdfCOunt` contains `1`, then the command the shell will be looking for is `[$pdfCount`, which is `[1`, and is a command that does not exists, hence the error message you are seeing.